# Physical browser can't access python webserver code on virtualbox?

Tags: python-2.7, webserver, virtualbox

Why i can't access this code from my physical PC browser?
   i build this code on Virtualbox, please help me. see the pict below

```
import socket

HOST, PORT = '', 8888

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)
print 'Serving HTTP on port %s ...' % PORT
while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)
    print request

    http_response = """\
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Hello, World!
"""
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)
    client_connection.close()
```

[refuse to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FNc4.png)

Comment: What type of network adapter did you set on your virtual machine? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606853/virtualbox-access-to-website-which-is-hosted-virtualbox?rq=1  Possible duplicate

Comment: NAT and host only adapter, both virtual and physical PC can PING each other